# where is the default __str__ function located in python?

Tags: python

I was trying to understand the class and objects in python and this question pops up in my mind. I was guessing that the default `__str__` function is defined inside of the object class. All the user defined classes and built-in classes are subclasses of the object class. That's why they can have accesses to the default `__str__` function. If you do not like the default `__str__` function, you can override it by defining your own `__str__` function in the class function defined by yourself. Did I understand it correctly? Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Technically, all classes have `__repr__`, and objects whose class lacks `__str__` fallback to the `__repr__` when you call `str()` on them. You can see [the code for that in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/object.c#L524), where `PyObject_Repr` is called if `tp_str` (the C level slot for `__str__`) isn't set.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you should make your comment an answer because it really does answer the question